# Issues with the nomencl package [LATEX]

Tags: latex, nomenclature

So I am using the nomencl package to define variables throughout my thesis.

After i run PdfLatex once, I run makeindex Skeleton.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o Skeleton.nls
to generate the index for the nomencl package. This works fine, but instead of e. g.

L [definition] page 35, 36 it outputs:

L [definition] page 35

L [definition] page 36

which will make the variables list incredibly long.

How can I fix this?

I use \nomenclature{L}{definition} on each page to declare the variable.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper]{book}


\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature



\begin{document}

\printnomenclature


\subsection{Specific surface area}
\label{ssasect}
Specific surface area (\textit{SSA})\nomenclature{SSA}{specific surface 
area} is the area per gram of nanoparticles, or more precisely,

\begin{equation}
SSA =  \frac{S_{p}}{V\rho}, 
\label{ssaeq}
\end{equation}
\nomenclature{SSA}{specific surface area}


where \textit{S$_p$} is the particle surface area, \textit{V} the particle 
volume  and $\rho$\nomenclature{$\rho$}{density} the cellulose density 
(1.55 g/cm$^3$).\cite{Vol1970} The specific surface area is important as 
surfaces are more reactive, and it  is thus an indirect measure of the 
relative reactivity of (nano)particles. Equation \ref{ssaeq} may be 
developed further by considering a cylindrical nanocellulose with diameter 
\textit{L}\nomenclature{L}{nanocellulose length} and radius 
\textit{r}\nomenclature{r}{radius}, and expressing the surface and volume 
as in Equation \ref{ci}, finally obtaining: 

\newpage 

\begin{equation}
SSA = \frac{\pi (2rL + 2r^{2})}{V\rho}.   
\label{ci2}
\end{equation}

\nomenclature{SSA}{specific surface area}


\end{document}
```

This produces one entry per word, and thus

SSA page 1 
SSA page 1
SSA page 2

Fix?

Comment: Provide a minimal working example, please.

Comment: Tried to make a mwe, and suddenly it worked. Don't know why though...

Comment: I couldn't resolve it after all

Comment: I added a MWE. Thanks.